# Difference in differences without a control group

Tags: sas, biostatistics, difference-in-difference

I am interested in learning how to do a difference in differences without a control group using SAS.

In my data, everyone has been affected by the exposure (policy change), is it even possible to do this considering that there is no control group?

Comment: Is everyone exposed to the policy at the same time or is there a more gradual roll-out? Do you have a panel, or a series of cross-sections data structure?

Answer (score 1):

in general, you can not use difference-in-difference approach to evaluate the affection without control group.
but if you have these persons's historic data, you may use their historic data as control group to roughly compare them before vs policy change.

Comment: You might consider adding under what assumptions this recovers the treatment effect (no trends).

Comment: Interesting. Doesn’t using historic data introduce measurement error into the model? This is essentially the treated unit’s data lagged by some period.